# Jquery html() function

Tags: jquery, html

I need to append a html file inside a div.

While doing jquery html(), it is removing the html & body tags.

How to retain those tags?

Refer this snippet:

```js
$('.html-file').html('<html><p>Hello</p></html>'); //it is removing html tag
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="html-file">
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to add the `<html>` tag agian. This should only be added once

Comment: if you want to show the text then `.text()` is what you need

Comment: The question is, *why* do you want to keep them? What's the [real problem](http://xyproblem.info/) you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am getting a html mail template file from server and put it in a div so that the user can edit the text & I will update those changes in html directly & finally I will send that html to the server.

Comment: Yeah, well, this is really not the right way to do it. Interactive HTML editor inside a web page is a bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.html-file').html('<p>Hello</p>');
```

There is no need to add `html` tag in `div`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.html-file').append('<p>Hello</p>')
```

If you need to 'append' content to div.